# Reconhecimento de voz em python

Tags: python-3.x

Queria sugestões de bibliotecas de reconhecimento(quando você fala e o computador escreve) de voz em Python, que sejam compatíveis com o windows, fáceis de baixar e claro em Python 3

Comment: A minha pergunta é sobre reconhecimento de voz(quando você fala e o computador escreve) n de síntese de voz(você escreve e o computador fala)

Comment: Eu votei para fechar a pergunta como fora do escopo , pois, ao meu ver, a resposta seria apenas um link ou seria ampla demais para responder. De qualquer forma, buscando *python speech to text* no Google você já acha material para iniciar seus estudos.

Comment: @Mat4guia falta de atenção minha, retirei o voto de fechamento e respondi.

Comment: obg @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: ok,@AndersonCarlosWoss,e obrigado por responder minha pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Existe o *SpeechRecognition* que suporta as seguintes APIs/motores:

- [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/) (funciona offline!)
- Google Speech Recognition
- [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/)
- [Wit.ai](https://wit.ai/)
- [Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api)
- [Houndify API](https://houndify.com/)
- [IBM Speech to Text](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/speech-to-text.html)
- [Snowboy Hotword Detection](https://snowboy.kitt.ai/) (funciona offline!)

Para instalar use o `pip`, se não tiver instalado baixe-o, veja este link. Depois de instalar o pip execute este comando, verifique se tem o `PyAudio` (é um dos recursos necessários) instalando se não tiver execute o comando:

```
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

Então depois execute:

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Depois de instalado ambos você pode testar usando o comando:

```
python -m speech_recognition
```

Exemplo de teste com PyAudio:

> ```
> C:\Users\guilherme\Desktop>python -m speech_recognition
> A moment of silence, please...
> Set minimum energy threshold to 257.2594761232556
> Say something!
> Got it! Now to recognize it...
> You said hello stack overflow
> Say something!
> ```

- `Say something!` foi o momento que o software iniciou e então eu falei no microfone *"hello stack overflow"*
- `Got it! Now to recognize it...` ocorreu quando ele entendeu o que eu disse
- `You said` informa o que foi dito no microfone

---

### Requisitos e recursos necessários para funcionar

- Python 2.6, 2.7 ou 3.3+
- PyAudio 0.2.11+ (necessário para o microfone, que parece o seu caso)
- PocketSphinx (necessário somente se for usar do Sphinx recognizer, recognizer_instance.recognize_sphinx)
- Google API Client Library for Python (necessário somente se for usar do Google Cloud Speech API, recognizer_instance.recognize_google_cloud)
- FLAC encoder (necessário somente em sistemas não baseados em x86 -
  Windows/Linux/OS X)

---

### Exemplos

Os exemplos podem ser baixados em https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/examples

Tem exemplo para microfone ou ler arquivo áudio

---

### Referencias da API

Segue o link com as referencias da API https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst

> Assim que possível irei enumerar todas aqui em português